# C program to return the rightmost index of string t in string s

Tags: c, string, char

I am new to C and trying to write a program to print the rightmost occurrence of char string in string s but the below code always returns -1 also I have initialized variable k in for loop but the code does not compile until I initialize k=0 where it is declared.Please see the code below and help me figure out what mistakes I have done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int store[100];
int strrindex(char s[], char t[]);
main()
{
    char s[] = "Ah Love! could you and I with Fate conspire\0";
    char t[] = "ould\0";
    int l = strrindex(s, t); 
    printf("Location=%d", l);
}
int index = 0;
int strrindex(char s[], char t[])
{
    int l = strlen(s);
    int k= 0;
    int c = 0;

    for (int i =0; i <l; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i, k = 0; t[k] != '\0'&& s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
            ;

        if ((k>0)&&(t[k]=='\0'))
            store[index++] = i;     
    }
    if (index > 0)
        return store[index - 1];
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: I'm astounded at the number of answers that fail to realize the for-loop with no body is *intentional*.

Comment: I suspected. Count your `k` decls (see answer below).

Comment: the function strrchr() is made to do the job.  Otherwise, use strstr and keep calling it in a loop (saving the last successful return value) until it returns a failure indication, the the saved last successful returned value is the desired pointer

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this program.

1. You cannot omit the return type of `main`. Always write `int main()` or `int main (int argc, char* argv[])`. Enable warnings and pay attention to them.
2. You have unused variables in `strrindex`. Again, enable warnings and pay attention to them. You want zero warnings in all your code.
3. `\0` in the end of string literals is redundant, the compiler adds one for you. Just write `"ould"`, not `"ould\0"`.
4. You have global variables. This is bad. One of them is called `index`. This is illegal, `index` is a name of a function in `string.h`. A global array named `store` is redundant, as you only ever access one last element of it.
5. You have **two** variables named `k`. One has a for-loop scope, the other one is always 0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the redeclaration of `k` in the initializer-part of your for-loop. This:

```
int l = strlen(s);
int k= 0; // **DECLARED HERE**
int c = 0;

for (int i =0; i <l; i++)
{
    for (int j = i, k = 0; t[k] != '\0'&& s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
    // AND HERE=====^
```

The outer `k` is initialized to 0 and never changes. As a result, even if the inner-k eventually ends with a match, the outer `k` will never be equivalent.

Do this:

```
int l = strlen(s);
int c = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <l; i++)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int j = i; t[k] != '\0'&& s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
        ;
```

That should fix the immediate problem you're having.

---

**Alternate Implementation**

Included because you should know you don't need the index array at all:

```
int strrindex(const char s[], const char t[])
{
    size_t slen = strlen(s);
    size_t tlen = strlen(t);
    int res = -1;

    if (tlen && (tlen <= slen))
    {
        for (size_t i=0; i<=(slen - tlen); ++i)
        {
            const char *rhs = t;
            for (const char *lhs = s+i; *lhs && *lhs == *rhs; ++lhs, ++rhs);

            if (*rhs == 0)
                res = (int)i;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a redundant semicolon (`;`) after the inner `for` loop. This mean the loop runs an "executes" an empty block each iteration (i.e., does nothing), and the `if` statement you have is executed **after** the inner `for` is terminated.

Just remove it, and you should be fine:

```
for (int i =0; i <l; i++)
{
    for (int j = i, k = 0; t[k] != '\0'&& s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
    /* ; removed here */

        if ((k>0)&&(t[k]=='\0'))
            store[index++] = i;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `if` statement's condition in your inner `for` loop, you have written

```
for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
{
  for(int j=i,k=0;(t[k]!='\0' && s[j]==t[k]);j++,k++)
   {
     if((k>0) && (t[k]=='\0'))
           {store[index++]=i;}
}
}
```

You have written `t[k]=='\0'`, which means the `if` statement will always be false. It will be true only when `t[k]=='\0'`, but the inner `for` loop would have been terminated by then because of the condition `(t[k]!='\0' && s[j]==t[k])`. Thus the if statement is always `false`. Hence the value of `index` is never incremented and it is zero till the end. Thus , the final `if` statement is not executed and the function `strrindex()` always returns `-1`.

Hope this helps !

Comment: The for loop has been terminated before the if statement with a ; the if statement is after that.As said by Whozcraig its intentional.